# Need clarification re Product table and Sku table - BigCommerce

Tags: bigcommerce, sku

I see that the Sku fields are duplicated in the  Product table.

When creating a product in BigCommerce from info in an independent POS system:

1. If there is only one Sku, do we create a Sku record in addition to the Product record?
2. If there are two Skus associated with an image and description, do we put the info for the first Sku in the product record and create a Sku record for only the second product, or do we create a sku record for each of the 2 skus?

In another ecommerce solution, each product has at least one variant (the default variant), and if there are 2 variations, then there are 2 variant records. It seems as though the Sku table is like what I am familiar with for variants. But BigCommerce may handle this differently and put the data for the default "variation" in the product record, and only use Sku records when there is more than one variation.

Answer (score 0):

In BigCommerce (and some other systems), SKUs are considered unique identifiers. In BigCommerce, you can only have unique SKU once (no duplicating) and a unique product name (also not able to be duplicated).

SKUs in BC correspond to variants/combinations of options that make up a variant product. There is a default "parent product" or simple product associated with a parent SKU (if any) and then variants generally have unique SKUs, but aren't required to have SKUs.

If a product has variants, you do create additional skus in addition to the parent sku/product.

You can get a little bit more clarity through some of the API documentation for our [V3 catalog api](https://github.com/bigcommerce/api/blob/master/docs/v3-catalog.md)

Comment: Yes, I figured that the Sku record corresponds to variants, but I did not know -- even after looking at the api documentation -- whether I need a SKU record for the default variant that is included in the product record. From your answer, I should not have a Sku record for the variation that is included in the product record, only use it for when there are more than one variations. Yes?

Comment: I have searched "variants BigCommerce" and I do not see an answer to my last follow-up question.
v3 of the BigCommerce API now has a command to get all the variants, but they are having trouble updating "variant fields".